# How to fix controller redirect after removing turbolinks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I've removed turbolinks from my Rails 6.0.0 beta web application using Ruby 2.6.1 and upon doing so, whenever I update or create a chapter, a POST request will get sent to the database. But while the database will save the data, it will also try to redirect the page, but the browser does not redirect to anywhere and will still display the edit/new page.

This was not an issue before removing turbolinks. I have tried searching around but could not find any solution to this so far. I tried restarting the server and of course using `bundle update` beforehand to actually *remove* turbolinks.

**Chapter Controller**

```
def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @chapter = @book.chapters.find(params[:id])
    if @chapter.update(chapter_params)
        redirect_to book_chapter_path(@book, @chapter)
    else 
        ...
    end
end
...
  private
  def chapter_params
    params.require(:chapter).permit(:title, :content, :status)
  end
```

**chapters > edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @chapter, url: { action: "update" } do |form| %>
... 
<%= form.submit "Draft", class: "save-btn" %>
...
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :books do
    resources :chapters
  end
```

Normally I expect this output from the server logs after it's POST request to update/create the chapter in the database...

```
Started GET "/books/1/chapters/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-17 12:52:29 +1030
Processing by ChaptersController#show as HTML
```

But instead, it says

```
Started GET "/books/1/chapters/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-17 12:52:29 +1030
Processing by ChaptersController#show as JS
```

I think I understand why this is happening, but again, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default of `form_with` is Ajax(remote).

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

You should add `local: true`.

```
<%= form_with model: @chapter, url: { action: "update" }, local: true do |form| %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed everything.